# Can't connect to symfony 4 app through nginx container. Wrong docker compose or nginx host configuration?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm setting up docker compose environment with symfony 4 app based on Api-platform. After setting up docker-compose file, creating skeleton Api-platform app, adding nginx host configuration and running containers I have a problem with connection to this app. Chrome says "This site can’t be reached".
Below docker-compose.yml and app.conf for nginx. Do I do something wrong?

```
services:
  php-cli:
    image: bitnami/php-fpm:7.2
    user: "${UID-www-data}:${GID-www-data}"
    entrypoint: bash
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app:cached
  php-fpm:
    user: "${UID-www-data}:${GID-www-data}"
    image: bitnami/php-fpm:7.2
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    expose:
      - '9000'
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app:ro
      - ./var/log/php:/var/log/php
      - ./.docker/php/config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro
    working_dir: /usr/src/app

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.14-alpine
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app:ro
      - ./.docker/nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl:ro
      - ./.docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./.docker/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name my.app;

    return      301 https://my.app:443$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    server_name my.app;

    root /usr/src/app/public;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/my.app.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my.app.key;

    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    # Block hidden files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # remove trailing slashes
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        # Comment the next line and uncomment the next to enable dynamic resolution (incompatible with Kubernetes)
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        #resolver 127.0.0.11;
        #set $upstream_host php;
        #fastcgi_pass $upstream_host:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;

        include fastcgi_params;

        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/index.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
      return 404;
    }
}
```